# Как перезагрузить приложение на wpf?

Tags: wpf

Как сделать кнопку рестарта на wpf? Нашла в интернете этот код, но он просто выключает программу:

```
private void Restart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // обработчик события рестарта 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: Рестарт - это открыть и закрыть. Ну так закрывайте ранее запущенный процесс, а затем повторно его открывайте, в чем проблема то? В коде выше вы перезапускаете сам WPF, уверены, что это то, что вам надо?

Comment: Не то :( Но я не смог лучше додумать как перезагрузить. Была идея очистить детей канваса, в виде строчки Maincanvas.children.clear(), а потом перекопировать старт, но не получилось. Решила сделать перезапуск exe. Поэтому прошу помощи и так, и так. Если подскажите, в чем ошибка, буду рад!

Comment: Ну тогда мне не ясен ваш вопрос. Подумайте сейчас, а как поймет совершенно незнакомый человек то, что вы спрашиваете, тот, кто совершенно не знаком с вами, вашим проектом, кодом и проблемой, как вот ему понять все это? В заголовке вы пишете "Как перезагрузить консоль", ок, для меня консоль это CMD, запущенная отдельным процессом. Далее в коде вы закрываете сам WPF проект (что не сходится с тем, что в заголовке про консоль), а далее, в комментарии, вы пишете "была идея очистить канвас", что теперь вовсе не подходит под идею закрытия WPF или CMD. Ну и как это понимать прикажете? А еще С++ стоит.

Comment: Мне интересно именно как перезагрузить консольное приложение на WPF, я привел код примера, который не сработал. Может тут кто знает почему так. Удалил с++

Comment: WPF - это UI, приложение с интерфейсом, написанное на XAML, о какой консоли то речь?

Comment: да, вы правы, перепутал термины, это точно не консольное

Comment: тогда просто как перезагрузить приложение... У меня оно в итоге все равно просто закрывается

Comment: А какой смысл в перезапуске приложения? Его перезапускают только в случаях, где надо обновить, например его файлы (обновление приложения), все другие случаи спокойно решаются без перезапуска. Так может вы неверно решаете задачу?

Comment: И кстати, код, что в вопросе, успешно [перезапускает](https://i.imgur.com/Pg8CDE9.gif) приложение.

Comment: я вот пытаюсь понять почему у меня не перезапускает приложение, а просто выключает. Может есть какие-то нюансы. Начинается загрузка на курсоре и все

Comment: Попробуйте на чистом проекте ваш способ, если он не сработает, то дело скорей всего у вас в системе, либо студии, либо еще в чем-то и надо это найти. А если сработает, то дело в вашем проекте, вашем коде, предположу, что у вас есть некая логика, которая выдает ошибку при старте и после перезапуска вы ловите эту ошибку, что и приводит к закрытию его.

Comment: не работает на чистом проекте, visual studio новую версию скачал... Какие еще могут быть проблемы, которые можно подебажить?